# Передача большого количества данных Сервер-Клиент

Tags: java, сервер, spring-mvc, клиент-сервер, client

У меня есть Сервис написан на Джаве и клиентское веб-приложение spring MVC. На стороне сервиса я пишу запрос в поисковый движок ElasticSearch и получаю большое количество данных (до 100 000 объектов). Результат запроса я конвертирую в java List и передаю в мое веб приложение.(MyObject имеет всего несколько полей) Все эти данные мне нужно положить в эксель файл чтобы юзер их мог скачать при нажатии кнопки.

Мой вопрос в том, как более эффективней передать такое огромное количество данных из Сервиса в Веб приложение?

Сразу прошу прощение, я на стажировке и пока только учусь, никогда не работала с таким большим количеством данных так что многих вещей не понимаю. Объясните пожалуйста для новичка

Comment: Есть ли возможность сохранять файлик на сервере, а пользователю предоставлять ссылку? Получили запрос на поиск - нашли - сложили в эксельку  - отправили в браузер ссылку и статус - пользователь нажал скачать - получил поток и браузер скачивает файл.